# jQgrid In-Line Edit:-How to set specific data type to a particular cell in jQgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using In-Line Edit:I have created jQgrid in which only one cell is used in edit mode.I need to restrict cell editing with specific data type.eg. 2nd cell of first row should be string,2nd cell of second row should be Date,2nd cell of first row should be Integer etc...
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the **beforeEditCell** event that gets fired when a user modifies the contents of a cell and change the **edittype** property on the selected cell to be whatever datatype you want.

Comment: can i use edit type property directly as it'a a property of colModel...may be i didn't got u..plz explain it more if u don't mind...